# Why is the Grails Quartz plugin failing?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

After making a few changes to my already-deployed Grails app, I attempted to recompile the WAR file, and started receiving this error (obviously shorted a bit):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
    with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServeletContext resource
    [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
    nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.Scheduler
```

I haven't had any problems with Quartz before this with this app.  `grails clean` and deleting every part of my cache (including the `.ivy2` folder) hasn't helped.  Googling hasn't returned anything useful.  Help?

Comment: I know you said you did a clean and deleted your cache.  Did you also blow away your ~/.grails directory (at least the part for your project?)  Also, do you get this same error both with generating a war and running a plain grails run-app?

Comment: Oh yes, I did that many, many times.  The only times I get the same error is when I generate the war and place it in a servlet container (like Tomcat) or if I use the run-war command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.  I finally figured out the cause of the problem.  My app is using the Grails Webflow plugin, which is not included by default with 1.3.3 and higher.  So, I had to find it from other sources.  Namely, other Maven repositories.

Even though I only needed the Webflow plugin, each time I would download all of the resources, I would pull in an extremely large amount.  I can only assume that the jar were overwriting the jars I already had in place.  After some digging, I was able to find the repository that was causing the problems, and deleted it from my BuildConfig.groovy file.

Now that's a headache.

Comment: which plugin did you install or delete? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I'd love to be more specific, but this was over 4 years ago.